# relation between the space C[a,b] and L∞[a,b]

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I don't really know a lot about spaces and relation between them, so I'm not really on good terms with them. Let $L_{\infty}[a,b]$ denote the space of all essentially bounded functions on [a,b] with the norm $||f||=ess\sup|f|$. What would exactly be the difference between $L_{\infty}[a,b]$ and $C[a,b]$ (the space of continuous function on $[a,b]$). I want to use the triangular inequality for functions $f$ and $g$, such that $f \in L_{\infty}[a,b]$ and $g \in C[a,b]$ with their associated norm. How can I connect these two spaces with each other and finally use one space? Do the theorems in $L_{\infty}[a,b]$ hold for $C[a,b]$ or inversed??. I'm not actually dealing with these spaces. I've tried in Google and found nothing useful.

Answer (score 2):

The space $C[a,b]$ can be homomorphicaly and isometricaly embedded into $L_{\infty}[a,b].$ That is the function $$C[a,b]\ni f\to f\in L_{\infty}[a,b]$$
is linear isometry.
So if you have any property that is true for any subspace of $L_{\infty}[a,b]$ then this property must be true also for $C[a,b].$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Excuse me, you means that C[a,b] is subspace of L∞[a,b]? and if some theorems hold for functions in L∞[a,b] they must hold for C[a,b]? Do I understand it true?

Answer (score 2):

Every continuous function on a compact set (e.g. the interval $[a,b]$) is bounded, therefore it makes sense to consider it as an element of $L_\infty[a,b]$. Notice that the essential supremum coincide with the supremum for a continuous function. Therefore every continuous function can be seen as an element of $L_\infty[a,b]$ and its $C[a,b]$-norm coincide with its $L_\infty[a,b]$-norm. In other words, $C[a,b]$ can be isometrically embedded in $L_\infty[a,b]$.